# Почему элементы переменной не замещаются?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь понять след. код (буду комментировать, чтобы было видно путь моего мышления, чтобы могли меня понять):

```
word = "moloko" #слово которое нужно угадать
so_far = "x" * len(word) по одному x на букву, которую надо угадать
# пока слово не угадано
while so_far != word:
Просим пользователя ввести букву
guess = input("")
если буква есть в слове, которое надо угадать
if guess in word: 
new = "" #создаем пустую строку для добавления элементов
    for i in range(len(word)):#итерация выполняется 6 раз(длина слова)
        if  guess==word[i]: #если буква есть угадываемом слове
            new = new + guess #добавляем в переменную букву
            print(new)
        else:#иначе
            new = new + so_far[i] #добавляем x
            print(new)
            # print(so_far[i])
    so_far = new
```

На выходе, допустим если ввести первой буквой "o", будет xoxoxo, и если затем "м", будет moxoxo. Так вот вопрос, разве переменная new, куда записывается буквы и x, при вводе другой буквы, которая есть в слове, допустим "м", не должна ли полностью меняться на mxxxx? Объясните пжл, я видимо не до конца понимаю этот код!(((( Я пол дня и уже вечер не могу понять, вернее я понял, но не до конца понимаю, как происходит итерация в данном коде

Comment: Голова кругом уже идет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот в этой строке:

```
new = new + so_far[i] #добавляем x
```

Ваш комментарий верен только для самого первого угадывания, когда у нас действительно в `so_far` лежат одни иксы.

Однако уже после первого угадывания, последняя строчка:

```
so_far = new
```

записывает в `so_far` текущий `new`. Поэтому после первого угадывания в `so_far` лежат уже не шесть иксов, а `'xoxoxo'`.

Comment: Скажите а при вводе второй буквы, разве она не должна замещать предыдущую букву (o)? я думал, т.е. первый вод буквы "o" выдаст - xoxoxo, а второй ввод буквы "m" выдаст - moxoxo, а я думал, что буква "o" будет замещена "x" и получится mxxxx, однако, она получается остается на месте?

Comment: Все, я понял, она не замещается, так как выполняется условие else)))Вот это дааааааааа...........!!!!!